# GWT Designer on Juno (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I've read about problems with GWT Designer with Ubuntu and there is not a Juno update site?  Anyone confirmed that this setup with work?  Ubunto 12.10.

Comment: This has worked for me pretty fine: http://blog.romanvlasenko.com/?p=100 :)

Comment: The update site https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 does include now GWT Designer (I was able to install and use it but I´m on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

I too had some issues with it. Eclipse was crashing when switching to designer view. What worked for me was installing [xulrunner 1.9.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xulrunner-1.9.2_1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb), setting `export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=false` before starting Eclipse.

Comment: Still not working for me.  It freezes while loading and sometimes crashes Eclipse with no message.

Answer (score 0):

I had to 
1) export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=false
2) install 64 bit nightly build of xulrunner (http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/2011/11/2011-11-01-03-32-27-mozilla-1.9.2/) 
3) insert -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/local/xulrunner at the end of eclipse.ini